# Mask Money plugin

Tags: gratis, javascript

I'm looking for a plugin in JavaScript (or using the JavaScript library jQuery), that is cost-free and is able to provide:

- Allow prefix (allow to enable/disable the feature)
- Allow suffix (allow to enable/disable the feature)
- Able to define `thousands` and `decimal` values (dot or comma)
- block copy and paste without numeric value (allow copy and paste of numeric value)

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
  - <kbd>Right click</kbd> → <kbd>Paste</kbd>
- Be jQuery **or** pure JavaScript
- No cost

---

I tried the [Jquery-maskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) and it's great, but it allows copy and paste. I also tried the [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) that is missing the prefix/suffix needy.

I didn't want to have to add [another code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-ctrlv-paste-with-jquery) to manage the copy and paste in maskMoney.